# Use silverlight in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Is it possible? I'm not familiar with silverlight architecture, but i know about wpf and asp.net mvc. is it possible to replace mvc view page with silverlight ones?

Comment: You can put silverlight application even in html page.

Comment: would u give a simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't replace an MVC view page with a silverlight one. But you can embed a silverlight app in one.

Comment: would u give a simple example.

Comment: I did a little search and it's explained pretty well in this article. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/09/silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx